# Ruby: what is wrong with this change_keys functions?

Tags: ruby

```
class Klass
  attr_accessor :keys
  def change_keys(opt)
    if opt == 1
      keys = [keys[0], keys[keys.length - 1]]
    else
      tmp = keys[0]
      keys[0] = keys[keys.length-1]
      keys[keys.length-1] = tmp
    end
    keys
  end
end
klass = Klass.new
klass.keys = [1,2,3,4,5]

# puts klass.change_keys(1)
# puts klass.change_keys(2)
```

This is not working at all, the error says: undefined method '[]' method for nil:NilClass

Comment: a) Considering that the last two lines are commented, I am pretty sure that code doesn't display any error b) assuming they are not meant to be commented: where is the "keys" coming from? you named your variable `klass`, not `keys`

Comment: I believe there is a big error in my code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby interprets  `keys[0]` and the others in line 5 as local variables because it has seen a `keys = ...` . There is an ambiguity in Ruby grammar when it comes to differentiate local variables from method calls without arguments that gets disambiguated by that heuristic. that is, if the parser sees an assignment to that identifier then is a local variable if not is a method call.

You can solve this by referring to self.keys instead. to make clear that you want to use the accessor method.

```
class Klass
  attr_accessor :keys
  def change_keys(opt)
    if opt == 1
      self.keys = [keys[0], keys[keys.length - 1]]
    else
      tmp = keys[0]
      keys[0] = keys[keys.length-1]
      keys[keys.length-1] = tmp
    end
    keys
  end
end
klass = Klass.new
klass.keys = [1,2,3,4,5]

puts klass.change_keys(1)
puts klass.change_keys(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're expecting `keys`, within your `change_keys` method, to refer to an instance variable (the same one as you set explicitly by writing `klass.keys = [1,2,3,4,5]`), but it doesn't. You want `@keys` instead.

(There are programming languages, such as C++ and Smalltalk and Java, in which unadorned variable names are automatically taken to refer to instance variables. Ruby isn't one of them.)

Answer (score -1):

You did not define an instance variable named keys to reference it. I would add the initialization and use the @keys instance variable:

```
class Klass
  #attr_accessor :keys
  def initialize(keys)
    @keys = keys
  end

  def change_keys(opt)
    if opt == 1
      @keys = [@keys[0], @keys[@keys.length - 1]]
    else
      tmp = @keys[0]
      @keys[0] = @keys[@keys.length-1]
      @keys[@keys.length-1] = tmp
    end
    @keys
  end
end
klass = Klass.new([1,2,3,4,5])

# puts keys.change_keys(1)
# puts keys.change_keys(2)
```

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: change keys to @keys certainly works, but what if I define a method: def keys; return @keys; end ?

Comment: His call to Klass#keys= initializes @keys, so that's not the problem.

Comment: This would work fine. It is what the attr_accessor does. Both through attr_accessor or a method named keys you would have access to the instance @keys variable. The @ is ruby way to differentiate variable scope. @@keys would be a class variable and $keys a global variable.

Comment: Yeap dominikh, there was no problem in there. It was just a matter of not giving direct access to an instance variable if it was just for initialization. I should not have changed his code in there.

Answer (score -1):

Attributes are instance variables, so you should be referring to `keys` as `@keys` everywhere within your method.

Comment: Using `keys` would work if it weren't for what @ecerulm said. `keys` would call the attribute reader, and that's in fact a common pattern.